# Error creating KML when using Circle in image style

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I am using a circle within an image element in a style for a Point when drawing and all works well until I try to render it out using KML.writeFeatures(), and I get this error:

***Uncaught TypeError: style.getSrc is not a function.***

```
sty = new ol.style.Style({  
          image: new ol.style.Circle({  
                     radius: 12,                
                     fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: "#990000" })
                 })
      }); 

e.feature.setStyle(sty);

        ...

kml = new ol.format.KML().writeFeatures(features);
```

Is this a bug, with OL3, thinking it's an icon? 
It catches the error here:

```
ol.format.KML.writeIconStyle_ = function(node, style, objectStack) {
    var /** @type {ol.xml.NodeStackItem} */ context = {node: node};
    var properties = {};
--->var src = style.getSrc();<---
    var size = style.getSize();
    var iconImageSize = style.getImageSize();
    var iconProperties = {
        'href': src
    };
}
```

Comment: `new ol.style.Fill({ "#990000" })` looks suspicious. Did you mean `new ol.style.Fill({ color: "#990000" })`? If the issue persists, then you have found a bug indeed.

Comment: Yes, I forgot the color: when I put it in the post to simplify the code to explain, but it's right in the  project